# How to set nested shadowRoot's css with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, polymer-3.x

**It's a little special here:**
I have a shadowRoot b, which is inside a shadowRoot a. So it is a nested shadow root(I use polymer to build web-component, and I import material design component to my polymer project, which leads this situation)
I tried :

```
const temp = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('mwc-fab.zoom-button');
```

and print `temp` in console:
[image]
Let me explain a bit more
the `mwc-fab` is a shadow root, which I can access through the `querySelector` method on above. 

**Now I want to have access the `button` which is the shadow root of `mwc-fab`, and then change the style of that shadow root with js,** but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you share some example?

Comment: @Tico I just explained a bit more

Comment: I got the question, I'm just trying to replicate. The answer below worked for me (not the same `class`, but the method).

Answer (score 0):

It'd work fine - try `mdc-fab` not `mac-fab`:

```
temp.querySelector("button.mdc-fab").style.color = "red";
```

Comment: It is my bad typing it wrong on my question, I just edited it. I used mdc-fab the same way as your answer but it didn't work. The querySelector just return null.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have nested ShadowDOMs you need to query inside each of them.

```
const fab = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('mwc-fab.zoom-button');
const button = fab.shadowRoot.querySelector('button.mdc-fab');
```